# Angular 2 dynamic routing

Tags: wordpress, angular, angular2-routing

I'm converting an existing db (Wordpress) driven site to an Angular 2 front end, keeping the backend as is. I'm at the routing stage and I want to create the routes from JSON data pulled from the db.

So, I've created a service to pull the data from the db and a separate routing module to register the routes:

```
app-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NavService } from './nav.service';

var navService: NavService;
const routes: Routes = navService.getRoutes();

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRouting{}
```

---

```
nav.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()

export class SiteNavService{
    private _navUrl = 'pathtofile/?action=ajax_site_nav';
constructor(private _http: Http){}
    getNav(){
        return this._http.get(this._navUrl)
        .map( res => res.json())
        .toPromise();
    }

}
```

The service is registered in the app.module.ts providers array and the routing module in the imports array. I can't get nav.service to work in the routing module file.

Answer (score 1):

I've just now been working on trying to add routes dynamically to angular 2 and found that getting the current routes with

`this.router.config`

and then changing them and applying the changes with

`this.router.resetConfig(newRoutes);`

Worked pretty well
I have my demo project here that might help where team members are dynamically added from json https://github.com/davidejones/angular2-routertest

Comment: I can see what you've done but it's not what I am trying to achieve and I am starting to think it's not possible. I want to pull the router configuration from the db. So, paths and their respective component names are stored in the db along with any other router properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using Xo for Angular: https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/

Xo creates dynamic routes based on your WordPress content, posts, pages, etc.

The secret sauce making this possible is the use of loadChildren in the Angular Route definition to lazy load a particular module. This is necessary as otherwise Route expects a component from an import that isn't realistic.

Example of this output from the docs site API: https://angularxo.io/xo-api/routes/get

Then in the Angular App using the angular-xo module these routes are loaded and updated by calling: router.resetConfig(response.routes);

Taken from this file: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-node/blob/master/lib/src/services/route.service.ts

Full disclosure, I am the author of the above plugin.

More docs (work in progress): https://angularxo.io

Example theme: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-material